# Draw network or graph from matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, matrix

How do I draw a sequence of frames of a network with the help of a transition matrix?
I have a matrix that denotes a graph. The matrix changes with iterations. Can anyone give me an insight of what functions I can use to create the series of the network?

```
      original=[0.06    0.57    0.37    0       0;
                0.57    0.06    0.37    0       0;
                0.37    0.57    0.03    0.03    0;
                0       0       0.03    0.13    0.84;
                0       0       0       0.84    0.16];
```

Suppose the, above is the matrix in question. Then the graph should be

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is related to [this earlier query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721377/plotting-a-graph-from-its-adjacency-matrix) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315322/how-to-graph-a-connectivity-adjacency-matrix-in-matlab). But here's an answer specific to your situation.

Given a weighted adjacency matrix:

```
 original =    [0.06    0.57    0.37    0       0;
                0.57    0.06    0.37    0       0;
                0.37    0.57    0.03    0.03    0;
                0       0       0.03    0.13    0.84;
                0       0       0       0.84    0.16];
```

you can first define the number of nodes in the network:

```
N = size(original,1);
```

and then a corresponding set of coordinates on the perimeter of a circle:

```
coords = [cos(2*pi*(1:N)/N); sin(2*pi*(1:N)/N)]';
```

Then you can plot the graph using `gplot`:

```
gplot(original, coords)
```

and mark the vertices using `text`:

```
text(coords(:,1) - 0.1, coords(:,2) + 0.1, num2str((1:N)'), 'FontSize', 14)
```

Note that the `gplot` function does not weight the lines by connection strength; the matrix element (i,j) is treated as binary, indicating absence or presence of a link between nodes i and j.

Comment: @happyme, can you be more specific regarding your problem ? The code above executes without errors on my machine.