# Generating image based on density of lines

Tags: matlab, graphics, graph

I found this in a paper and have been trying to do the same.The objective is to join all stations with lines and then indicate the regions where the density of lines is high or low.

[image]

Note:the red dots indicate stations

Is there is software which could do this ? 
I tried this in Maltab but the result were incorrect for more than 3 stations .

Comment: what did you tried in matlab. show the code, otherwise we may not be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, the function you're looking for is gplot: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html
(you can see an asnwer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308565/draw-network-or-graph-from-matrix-in-matlab)).

The idea is: if you have a list of n points, you need a n-by-2 matrix that defines the coordinates for each point, and another matrix that defines which nodes should be linked. For instance:

```
A=[0 1 1;1 0 0;1 0 0];
c=[1 1; 2 2; 3 1];
gplot(A,c)
```

For the second graph, I'm less familiar: what I usually see is people use something like the first graph with less thick lines and more space, so you can get the feeling of density while actually being able to see why it exists (e.g. a node that links to many others).

Still, if you want to plot something like the second graph, it is less of a matter of Matlab coding and more of figuring out which function generates the "density". After you have that, you can use `countour`. You need a function that, for each (x,y) coordinate, calculates distances to all lines and aggregate this vector in a parametric way (e.g. given the vector d, you could have something like `sum(exp(-Z*d))` for some constant `Z`, or try different functions). Also note that, by the look of the graph you've shown, it is possible that the density is also weighted by the "strength" of each link, if there's such a thing.

Comment: first part corresponds to the type of data which i already have.I am more concerned with the second part.

Comment: Does the paper say anything about how the graph was plotted, perhaps in an (online) appendix? By this, I mean not necessarily the code/tool they used, but perhaps an explanation of how to calculate the density function.
As the other comment mentioned, it would be helpful to know your code (that is, a small example that shows what you were trying to do in Matlab).