# How can I use Matlab to plot a network graph from a Matrix

Tags: matlab, networking, matrix, graph

I hope someone is able to help me provide an insight into my problem?

I am working on an academic project that simulates road network in a small town. For the sake of simplicity, my road network is a nxn matrix (an example is the 9x9 matrixA below)...

```
matrixA =
a1    b2    c3    d4    e5    f6    g7    h8    i9
a2    b0    c0    d0    e5    f0    g0    h0    i9
a3    b0    c0    d0    e5    f0    g0    h0    i9
a4    b0    c0    d0    e5    f0    g0    h0    i9
a5    b5    c5    d5    e5    f5    g5    h5    i9
a6    b0    c0    d0    e5    f0    g0    h0    i9
a7    b0    c0    d0    e5    f0    g0    h0    i9
a8    b0    c0    d0    e5    f0    g0    h0    i9
a9    b9    c9    d9    e9    f9    g9    h9    i9
```

My aim is to generate a graph from the above matrix, with the folowing properties:
All the non-zero elemets are vertices in the graph and connected top-down and sideways (connectors will be directed edges), as long as there is a non-zero element. So for example, element a1 is connected to b2; b2 is connected to c3; and c3 is connected to d4 etc. Also a1 is connected to a2; a2 to a3; a3 to a4; and a4 to a5. Subsequently, a5 is connect to nothwords, southwards and to the right (i.e a5 is connected to a4, b5 and a6).

The ultimate aim is to be able to search the graph and traverse it too.

Any advice/guidance is appreciated. Please let em know if I need to provide further information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `gplot`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. 

@Cleb, I have started by atomatically generating the matrix. Now I'm stock since I don't know how to identify and pass the nodes to a plotter in matlab. 

Dan, I have seen this link and several other including the following...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308565/draw-network-or-graph-from-matrix-in-matlab
http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19580-plot-a-directed-graph--v2-0-

I suppose my probel using the gplot is that I need help identifying the coordinates.

Thanks,

Comment: `gplot` is really good idea!
I just want to say about one more way of introduction your data - use `pcolor` and work with it smth like black colour is a wall, white - road and etcetera.

Comment: Many thanks @Mikhail_Sam - as I menitoned, my problem is generating the coordinates, I don't know how to generate the coordinates, which gplot needs to plot the graph. Otherwise, gplot seems the right option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try and process your matrix a bit more. If you were to use an index value for each of the matrix entries (a1 = 1, b2 = 2 etc.) you could generate a sparse matrix that represents your graph.

Your above example would then lead to a graph that looks as follows (in sparse methodology of Matlab):

```
(1,2)  1
(1,10) 1
(2,3)  1
(3,4)  1
(4,5)  1
(5,6)  1
(5,14) 1
.
.
.
(10,19) 1
(14,23) 1
.
.
.
```

For simplicity's sake I assumed all the edges to have value 1. This is of course up to you.

Having generated a sparse matrix (G) of this kind, you can display it using the following command

```
h = view(biograph(G,[],'ShowWeights','on'))
```

There are then also a bunch of other methods that can be used with a graph that is set up this way, e.g. max flow analysis (http://ch.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphmaxflow.html)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Your suggestion sounds great - although I will be representing the nodes with specific values. I will try it and update soon. Thanks

Comment: To keep a certain value for each node, you could just "self-assign" the value to it (e.g. for a1: (1,1)=12). This would not influence the flow and can easily be retrieved for further processing if needed.